# How to write a procedure in sql server that takes table name as a input parameter and displays the data in the table as an output

Tags: sql-server

How to write a procedure in sql server that takes table name as a input parameter and displays the data in the table as an output

```
create procedure Fetch_Table_Data


    @Table_name varchar(50)
    'Select* from'+'@Table_name'
```

This is showing error

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: You need Dynamic SQL for that.

Comment: Please refer BOL and learn how to write a stored procedure first

Comment: @Raj What does BOL stand for?

Comment: @Radu: BOL is Books OnLine, ie. the online documentation for SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

use sp_executesql

"Executes a Transact-SQL statement or batch that can be reused many times, or one that has been built dynamically. "

In your case it wil be

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 'Select * from'+@Table_name
```

UPD: Complete example

```
declare @tname nvarchar(50), @sql nvarchar(50)
select @tname = 'dbo.SomeTable'
select @sql = 'Select * from ' + @tname
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```